# Query regarding UK Visa Online Application Visa Sub Type Category option is not showing?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am filling inline application for UK visa and following issue is coming.As you can see in the picture visa sub type category is not showing. Because of it is not creating the application. Please share how to solve this issue. 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Visa4uk](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) website says,

> You may be able to apply using our [new service](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa) for visit visa
>   applications if you are applying for a:
>
> ```
> - Standard Visitor Visa
> ```

Just follow the link and apply with the new service.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, we cannot submit the application form using old service now.? Is it mandatory to use new service for application submission

Comment: @zohaib anwar It’s not a new service, the gov.uk site has been the portal for visit visa applications from outside the UK for at least 2 years

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually last year i have applied using this service and not used new one which you have shared as well and I am applying from Pakistan.

Answer (score 1):

Gov.uk says apply online https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply unless you’re from North Korea.